# Intent to Dial Pad and SMS APP are loading the wrong numbers

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, sms, phone-call

I'm building a screen with emergency services from specific countries around the globe and their numbers are usually not 10 digits long, 
example: `Australia = 13 11 14` and `UK plus ROI = 116 123`

I would like the user to click on these numbers and be taken to the dial pad regardless of their locale. 
This is what I have so far:

```
fun openDialApp(phoneNumber: String) {
        val dialIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
        dialIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        dialIntent.data = Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode(phoneNumber))
        startActivity(context, dialIntent, Bundle.EMPTY)
    }
```

This code does bring the user to the dial pad, however it inputs a totally different number. After debugging a bit more seems like there is something changing the number from what the string literally is to some other randomly generated number. Have any ideas why this is ?

Same issue happens when I try to send a user to their SMS app through the `American helpline number = 741741`. The code for this is below

```
fun openSmsApp(smsNumber: String) {
        val smsIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
        smsIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        smsIntent.data = Uri.parse("smsto:" + Uri.encode(smsNumber))
        startActivity(context, smsIntent, Bundle.EMPTY)
    }
```

Comment: What is your actual value of phoneNumber?  Because its expected to be a final uri like "tel:911" for the US-  no spaces allowed.

Comment: I'm using an emulator, so it doesn't have a phone number. However, I do see a recurring number which is: `(213) 182-0877` I think this might be a the default number to go to on an emulator, maybe someone can shine some light on this

Comment: I meant the variable phoneNumber passed into the openDialApp function.  For the function to work it needs to be just 0-9 and possibly a leading +, it can't have ()- or space

Comment: That worked for the most part, however, the sms still keeps loading the wrong number

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was that I was getting the id rather than the actual number:

here is the before code:

```
private fun bindViews() {
        header.leftIconView.clicks().bindToWithDispose(disposables) {
            viewModel.goBack()
        }

        lifelineAustraliaNumber.clicks().bindToWithDispose(disposables) {
            viewModel.openDialApp(R.string.lifeline_australia_number.toString())
        }
        mentalHealthAmericaTextNumber.clicks().bindToWithDispose(disposables) {
            viewModel.openSmsApp(R.string.mental_health_america_text_number.toString())
        }

        samaritansNumber.clicks().bindToWithDispose(disposables) {
            viewModel.openDialApp(R.string.samaritans_number.toString())
        }

    }
```

Here is the after code:

```
 private fun bindViews() {
        header.leftIconView.clicks().bindToWithDispose(disposables) {
            viewModel.goBack()
        }

        lifelineAustraliaNumber.clicks().bindToWithDispose(disposables) {
            viewModel.openDialApp(context.resources.getString(R.string.lifeline_australia_number))
        }
        mentalHealthAmericaTextNumber.clicks().bindToWithDispose(disposables) {
            viewModel.openSmsApp(context.resources.getString(R.string.mental_health_america_text_number))
        }

        samaritansNumber.clicks().bindToWithDispose(disposables) {
            viewModel.openDialApp(context.resources.getString(R.string.samaritans_number))
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps someone